# Woocommerce Show default variation price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm using Woocommerce and product variations and all my variations have a default variation defined.

How I can find the default variation and display its price?

This is the code I got so far, but it displays the cheapest variation price, and I'm looking for my default variation product price instead.

```
// Use WC 2.0 variable price format, now include sale price strikeout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
// Main Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'HERE YOUR LANGUAGE: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );
// Sale Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $prices );
$saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'HERE YOUR LANGUAGE: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
    $price = '<del>' . $saleprice . '</del> <ins>' . $price . '</ins>';
}
return $price;
```

I found the code example here [Woocommerce variation product price to show default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065821/woocommerce-variation-product-price-to-show-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my own solution, think it could be better, but I'm not a php developer, so feel free to add improvements.

```
function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
// Main Price
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$selectedPrice = '';

foreach ( $available_variations as $variation )
{
    $tmp = implode($variation['attributes']);

    if (strpos($tmp,'standard') !== false) {
        $selectedproduct = wc_get_product($variation['variation_id']);
        $price =  $selectedproduct->get_price();
        $selectedPrice = wc_price($price);
    }       
}

return $selectedPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I did not find answer for this question (how to display price from default product variation instead of price range?) so i created the code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

    function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {

        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $pav){
            $def=true;
            foreach($product->get_variation_default_attributes() as $defkey=>$defval){
                if($pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey]!=$defval){
                    $def=false;             
                }   
            }
            if($def){
                $price = $pav['display_price'];         
            }
        }   

        return woocommerce_price($price);

    }
```

This plugin show price from default variation, of course if you set default values before. Tested on woocommerce version 2.6.2.

Comment: it works, but not for variable product that have a discount price... there is any solutions ?

Comment: This is good but when you sort products by price, it uses the lowest variation price and not the default

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit to show discounted price as well.

```
// show default variation price
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $default_attributes = $product->get_variation_default_attributes();
    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
        $is_default=true;
        foreach($default_attributes as $attribute_key => $attribute_value) {
            if($variation['attributes']['attribute_' . $attribute_key] != $attribute_value){
                $is_default=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($is_default){
            return $variation['price_html'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version that works also for sale prices.

```
// Show default variation price including sale prices and old prices
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $default_attributes = $product->get_variation_default_attributes();

    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
        $is_default = true;

        foreach($default_attributes as $attribute_key => $attribute_value) {
            if($variation['attributes']['attribute_' . $attribute_key] != $attribute_value){
                $is_default = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if($is_default) {
            // Check if the variation has a sale price
            $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
            $variation_obj = wc_get_product($variation_id);

            if ($variation_obj->is_on_sale()) {
                $regular_price = wc_get_price_to_display($variation_obj, array('price' => $variation_obj->get_regular_price()));
                $sale_price = wc_get_price_to_display($variation_obj, array('price' => $variation_obj->get_sale_price()));
                return '<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del> <ins>' . wc_price($sale_price) . '</ins>';
            } else {
                return $variation_obj->get_price_html();
            }
        }
    }

    return $price;
}
```