# Display default and selected variation price from a woocommerce variable product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I've been looking over Stack for an answer but can't find one (even when reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997575/display-default-variation-price-woocommerce-products) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959707/woocommerce-display-variations-price-once-selected))

**Here my trouble**: i would like to display (or at least get the variable) of the default and selected price of a woocommerce variable product.

**System**: Wordpress 5,6 + woocommerce

With a **single product**, my code is working well and i obtain a display like this:
[Display for a single product with weight and price rewritten on right after quantity selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXani.png)

And code is the following:

```
global $woocommerce;
$productxyz = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
$priceproduct = $productxyz->get_regular_price();
$poidsproduct = $productxyz->get_weight();

// CODE FOR THE + AND - QUANTITY
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.decrement').click(function () {
  $moninput = $(this).nextAll('input#Qte');
  if( Number($moninput.val()) > $moninput.attr("min") ){
     $moninput.val(Number($moninput.val()) - 1);
  }else{
     $moninput.val($moninput.attr("min"));
  }
  Update_Price();
  event.preventDefault();
})
$('.increment').click(function () {
  $moninput = $(this).nextAll('input#Qte');
  $moninput.val(Number($moninput.val()) + 1);
  Update_Price();
  event.preventDefault();
})
$('#btn-cady').click(function () {
 $('[name="add-to-cart"]').click();
 event.preventDefault();
})

// CODE FOR THE TEXT DISPLAYED ON THE RIGHT OF THE QUANTITY SELECTOR
function Update_Price(){
  if($('input#Qte').attr('price') > 0){
    $total =  parseFloat($('input#Qte').val()) * $('input#Qte').attr('price');
    $qtyactuelle = parseFloat($('input#Qte').val());
    $('input[name="quantity"]').val($('input#Qte').val());
    console.log($total);
    if( $qtyactuelle < 2){
    $('.Qtotal h4').html("<font color='#401816'>pack soit " +($('input#Qte').attr('weight')*parseFloat($('input#Qte').val()))+"g |</font> "+parseFloat($total).toFixed(2)+" €");
    }
    if($qtyactuelle > 1){
    $('.Qtotal h4').html("<font color='#401816'>packs soit " +($('input#Qte').attr('weight')*parseFloat($('input#Qte').val()))+"g |</font> "+parseFloat($total).toFixed(2)+" €");
    }
  }
}
Update_Price();
});
```

But for a variation product... i feel so ashamed to show my result because when it's displaying well, function is not working. And when functions are working, display is very terrible
[Code result for variation product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M4RS.png)

I tried to use get_available_variations() and also the following foreach but...

```
foreach( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        $found = true;
        // Loop through variation attributes
        foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $key => $value ){
            $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key );
            // Searching for a matching variation as default
            if( isset($default_attributes[$taxonomy]) && $default_attributes[$taxonomy] != $value ){
                $found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If we get the default variation
        if( $found ) {
            $default_variaton = $variation;
            break;
        }
```

Has anyone an idea of how to developp it? I'm feeling speechless.

In advance, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

On WooCommerce variable product pages, product variation data is stored in the `data-product_variations` attribute of the multi-select `<form class="variation_form">` element. The variation data is stored in JSON format which you can then decode using the `JSON.parse()` method. There is no need to output this data yourself via PHP as WooCommerce already does it for you.

The JSON stored in the `data-product_variations` attribute includes the following price related properties:

- `display_price`
- `regular_price`
- `sale_price`

With a little bit of jQuery/JS, you can easily output or mutate the default or selected variation pricing with the above properties.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did use $product->get_display_price(); but even when using data-product_variations, i can't figure out how to obtain the selected regular_price. But i will continue to work on it. Thx!